# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: user.city
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, "accountName", city, email, avatar, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('sunny123', 'sunny kumar', 'Tumkur', 'sunny@gmail.com', 'default.jpg', '$2b$12$n3eEOEBhJ7aVEA4wctQn4O37jEYdgI0N2jqhNKm7Giy7Y7hxwaZIS')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

My User Model is

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True, nullable = False)
    accountName = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)
    avatar = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable = False, default = 'default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable = False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.accountName}','{self.city}','{self.email}', '{self.avatar}')"`enter code here`
```

And My Route is

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = SignUp()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username = form.username.data, accountName = form.accountName.data, city = form.city.data, email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your account has been created, now you can Signin', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('signin'))
    return render_template('signup.html', title = 'Sign Up', form = form)
```

whenever i am trying to add a user with city name eg: "abc" which is mentioned by a previous user then it is throwing an error, but in my User model unique = True is just for username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy as a library can be easily used for managing tables, even creating them, but **only for once**.

If you have had a unique `city` column previously, and you haven't changed it from the Database, it will keep reinforcing the unique constraint on the column.

Because for the database, it still has a unique constraint. You cannot remove the `UNIQUE` constraint using `ALTER` in SQLite.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013265/remove-unique-constraint-on-a-column-in-sqlite-database) for recreating the database safely.