# SQLite Append Trading Data to existing db is not working

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created my first SQLite database. The database has a table per ticker with Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume columns. When creating data for the first time, it is working fine. But as time progresses new data is available since this is daily ticker information. When trying to append the new time series data, it gives an error.

Error Inserting OHLCV to this ticker ABT Err: UNIQUE constraint failed: ABT.Date

I know the date for some of the entries would overlap. I need to just append the missing times.

Here is my code:

```
def insertData(db,tickers):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()
    for ticker in tickers:
        try:
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'alphavantage', start, end,api_key=AV_API_Key) #quandl stopped free data 2018
            print(df)
        except:
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end) #if quandl doesn't have, try yahoo
        print("===", ticker, "===")
        print(df.tail(1))
        for idx, val in df.iterrows():
            try:
                c.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO '{}' (Date, Open, High, Low, Close)"
                    "          VALUES(:Date, :Open, :High, :Low, :Close)".format(ticker),
                    {'Date':idx.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'),'Open':val['Open'],'High':val['High'],'Low':val['Low'],'Close':val['Close']})
            except Error as e:
                print("Error Inserting OHLCV to this ticker", ticker, "Err:", e)
    print("Inserted", ticker)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Please add the full error details.

Comment: just added. Error Inserting OHLCV to this ticker ABT Err: UNIQUE constraint failed: ABT.Date

Comment: The date column is defined with a unique constraint (perhaps when you created an index on it) remove it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013265/remove-unique-constraint-on-a-column-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: remove the column or remove the constraint? The link suggests doing it in SQLiteDatabaseBrowser. This isn't practical if I switch systems. Any way to do it with a python command?

Comment: How have you set up the tables for each ticker?

Comment: "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '{}' (Date DATETIME PRIMARY KEY, Open FLOAT, High FLOAT, Low FLOAT, Close FLOAT)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made the `Date` the primary key meaning its value must be unique for all rows but you are attempting to add a new row with a date that already exists, hence the error.

`DROP` the table (`DROP TABLE XXX;`) and recreate it without `Date` as the PK - If you want a PK then add an `AUTOINCREMENT` column.

```
CREATE TABLE "XXX" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Date"  DATETIME NOT NULL,
    "Open"  FLOAT,
    "High"  FLOAT,
    "Low"   FLOAT,
    "Close" FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

You can add a non-unique index to `Date` if you want it optimized for lookups:

```
CREATE INDEX "IX_XXX_Date" ON "XXX" (
    "Date"
);
```

Design wise 99% of the time its better to have a single table with a `ticker-name` column than a table-per-ticker.